# Upload script to google scripts gallery

Tags: javascript, google-docs, google-sheets, google-apps-script

Do anyone knows how to upload a script to google scripts gllery, so that i can install the script in the google spreadhseets and use that script in google docs(spreadsheets)

Answer (score 1):

As fas as I know, the only way to get your script in the gallery is to follow their instructions to make it public and they (Google) will publish it, but they have not published anything new in a couple of years.

Also, there is no way to easily install a script from one spreadsheet into another. The only way is to [cut-n-paste your script](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jmvidal/5035891157) from the editor window.